# Bridging an native android SDK - heremaps

Tags: android, react-native, here-api

Currently I am trying to bridge the Heremaps android sdk for react-native via external library. I have successfully bridged it in a local react-native project and am currently in the process of creating the android portion of the library.

Currently with the current implementation I have, I am running into this error when I try to run an android build:

> - What went wrong:
>     Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
>     Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
>     Could not find :HERE-sdk:.
>      Required by:
>          project :app > project :react-native-heremaps-bridge

The sdk lives in {libraryname}/android/app/libs in my external library

My android/app build.gradle in the external library looks likes this.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

def safeExtGet(prop, fallback) {
    rootProject.ext.has(prop) ? rootProject.ext.get(prop) : fallback
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion safeExtGet("compileSdkVersion", 28)
    buildToolsVersion safeExtGet("buildToolsVersion", '28.0.3')

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion safeExtGet('minSdkVersion', 17)
        targetSdkVersion safeExtGet('targetSdkVersion', 26)
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"                    nb 
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // React Native
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"

    // HereMaps SDK

    implementation(name:'HERE-sdk', ext:'aar')
}
```

and android level build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 17
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}
```

On the react-native side, my build.gradle on android/app level only has these changes:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project('{project-name}')
}
```

And my settings.gradle include these changes:

```
include ':{library name}'
project(':{library name}').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/{library name}/android/app')
```

And lastly in my MainApplication.java:

```
    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for
      // example:
      packages.add(new HeremapsPackage()); //<------added this line
      return packages;
    }
```

Any idea what I'm missing here? I would like to avoid adding the sdk in my main react-native app as that's close to 100mbs. Thank you!

Comment: hello i want bridging heremap sdk in android and i am working on react native project can you help i have no idea about bridging

Answer (score 0):

The gradle buildTypes should be same at root and app level to resolve the dependencies. Also If you are using lite version, you can think of upgrading the version of sdk.

> buildTypes{
>             debug{ ... }
>             release{ ... }
>       }

you have in your (app) build.gradle file, You have to include all the buildTypes{ } with same names as like

> buildTypes{
>         debug{ ... }
>         release{ ... } }

in to build.gradle files of All libraries/modules included in project.

clean and rebuild the project, the issue should be fixed.